# php if statement only returns 1st "if"

Tags: php, if-statement

My php must be wrong in the if statement somewhere. For some reason it only returns "Buy" in the array as the History Type, even when the raw data shows me otherwise. What have i done wrong?

```
$history = $api->get_wallet_history('USD');

$i = 0;
while ($i <= 9):
$history_date = $history[result][$i][Date];
//$history_date->format("m-d-y");
//print_r($history_date);

$history_type = $history[result][$i][Type];
if($history_type = 'spent'):
    $history_type = 'Buy';
    elseif($history_type = 'earned'):
        $history_type = 'Sold';
    elseif ($history_type = 'fee'):
        $history_type = 'Fee';
    else:
        $history_type = 'Error';
endif;
//print_r($history_type);

$history_usd = $history[result][$i][Balance][value];
$history_btc = $history[result][$i][Trade][Amount][value];
$history_amt = $history[result][$i][Value][value];
echo '<tr><td>'.$history_type.'</td><td>'.$history_amt.'</td><td>'.$history_usd.'</td><td>'.$history_btc.'</td><td>'.$history_date.'</td></tr>';
$i++;
endwhile;
```

Comment: Always remember, when comparing the string, use `==` instead of `=`. `=` in PHP is assignment operator.

Comment: why don't use `{}`...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that was true even in an "If" statement. 
Also I thought == meant "Absolutely Equals". i.e. if ($history_type "absolutely equals" 'spent'):

Its' clear now. Thanks to you all for the explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$history_type = 'spent'` must be `$history_type == 'spent'`

Assigments always returns assigment value. `$history_type = 'spent'` returns 'spent', which interpreted as `true`.

Your `if` must looks

```
if ($history_type == 'spent'):
    $history_type = 'Buy';
elseif ($history_type == 'earned'):
    $history_type = 'Sold';
elseif ($history_type == 'fee'):
    $history_type = 'Fee';
else:
    $history_type = 'Error';
endif;
```

[Assignment Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

To avoid possibility of this mistake you could change places of value and variable.

`'spent' = $history_type` -- never works
`'spent' == $history_type` -- works as expected

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning here instead of comparing:

```
 if ($history_type = 'spent'):
```

That's why it will always has the value of 'spent'